# Die Nutzung von "leben" als Verb im Dativ

Tags: dative

In Ludwig Laistners Übersetzung von "Exul ego clericus" gibt es einen Absatz, der mich als Muttersprachler (allerdings ist Grammatik bzw. das theoretische Wissen darüber in weite Ferne gerückt...) irgendwie stört:

Original:

> Literarum studiis vellem insudare, nisi quod inopia cogit me
> cessare.

Deutsch:

> Dem gelahrten Studium möcht' ich gerne leben; leider dass der Mangel
> mich zwingt es aufzugeben.

Quelle: https://www.lieder.net/lieder/get_text.html?TextId=137266

Was ich hier nicht verstehe ist die Verwendung des Wortes "leben" als Verb. Laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/leben) scheint hier die siebte Bedeutung des Wortes zu greifen:

```
sich einer Sache widmen, hingeben

ganz seiner Familie/für seine Familie leben
er lebt nur seiner Musik, für eine Idee
```

Wenn ich hier die Frage stelle: `Wem möchte ich gerne leben?` Dann hört sich für mich die Frage einfach nicht richtig an. Stört mich hier ein falsches Sprachgefühl, oder ist hier wirklich der Wurm drin?

Comment: "Wem" ist natürlich in den meisten Fällen Unsinn. "Was" (im Dativ) ist eher passend.

Comment: @tofro mit einigen illustren Ausnahmen, wie "seiner Familie" (Beispiel oben) oder "dem Herrn" in [Römer 14:8](https://www.erf.de/hoeren-sehen/erf-plus/audiothek/wort-zum-tag/roemer-14-8/73-2122): "Unser keiner lebet *ihm selber*... Leben wir, so leben wir *dem Herrn*" (herrlich [vertont](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9VhrQT0zfQ) von H. Schütz)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In deinem Beispielsatz ist eine sehr alte Form, ein sogenannter *dativus finalis*. Diese Anwendung des Dativs wurde aus dem Lateinischen übernommen (wo sie ziemlich üblich war und was man auch an deinem Beispiel sieht - es ist eine vollkommen wörtliche Übersetzung), und wird heute nur noch selten und nur in gehobener (geschraubter?) Sprache verwendet. Der *dativus finalis* drückt einen **Zweck** aus.

> Er lebt nur seiner Arbeit

Diese Form hat eigentlich nichts mit dem Verb zu tun, sondern eher mit dem Fall: Sie funktioniert auch ohne ein Verb wie z.B. in der ähnlichen Form

> Sie war ihm zu Willen

oder

> Es war ihm von Nutzen

oder

> Sie kamen ihnen zur Hilfe

(im Deutschen allerdings immer mit einer Präposition - aber im Dativ.

Da man im Deutschen bei einer Frage ("was?") den Dativ nicht markieren kann (er sicht aus wie ein Nominativ), kann man schlecht fragen

> Was lebt er?

(Obwohl das grammatikalisch richtig wäre) Und da der *dativus finalis* nur schlecht mit Personen funktioniert, kann man auch schlecht fragen

> Wem lebt er?

(Obwohl das auch richtig wäre). Die Form ist einfach zu ungebräuchlich, um mit einer Frage verständlich zu funktionieren.

Answer (score 0):

In der Tat funktioniert diese Formulierung nicht in Frageform. Sie ist schon in der Aussageform sperrig und gewöhnungsbedürftig bzw. veraltet. Gelegentlich findet man aber auch heute die Phrase, aber eher im Akkusativ.

> Er spielt nicht Fußball, er lebt den Fußball.

Oder

> Bescheidenheit darf man nicht nur im Mund führen, man muss sie auch leben!

Allenfalls, wenn der Kontext bereits aufgemacht ist,

> Klaus lebt den Fußball. 
> Was möchte ich gerne leben?

versteht man diese Fragekonstruktion. Dass sie mit Wem-Fall verständlich sein könnte bezweifle ich. Vielleicht 1879, als der Text entstand.

Fragt man ohne den Kontext "Was möchte ich gerne leben?" wird man wohl korrigiert zu "Wie möchte ich gerne leben!".

Comment: Tatsächlich hätte "er lebt dem Fußball" eine leicht andere Bedeutung als "er lebt den Fussball"

Comment: Nämlich? (MINDESTZEICHENPFLICHT)

Comment: *Er lebt dem Fussball* bedeutet, dass jemand sein gesamtes Leben dem Fussball opfert. *Den Fussball leben* kann man auch jeden Samstag von 15-18 Uhr im Stadion.

Comment: "Den Fußball leben" verstehe ich genauso. Wer sich nur 3h die Woche mit Fußball befasst interessiert sich eben auch für Fußball.

Comment: Da ist eben der Unterschied zwischen Interesse und Hingabe

Comment: Eben. (MINDESTZPFL.)